# Highcharts Drilldown xAxis Click Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using the drilldown.js module I am getting errors upon clicking of the xAxis label items (the underlined linked text):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBBox' of undefined
```

If I click a bar "point" it will then drill down but then double the points are rendered than what should show. For example if the drilldown series has 2 points what gets rendered is 4 points. If I use the drill up button and then re-click either the xAxis labels or the bar points it then shows the correct number of points on the drilldown series.

Here is the live [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/TK8Qy/).

Comment: It's a bug in drilldown module - doesn't work with hidden series. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3197). Thanks!

Comment: I await the fix with anticipation.

Comment: @PawełFus The github issue says it is fixed however it is not fixed on our end using the github master branch. getBBox error persists.

Comment: As I can see, it was reopened 1hour ago.